# Cors or Axios Error on Django Server and React frontend project

Tags: reactjs, django, axios, cors

When trying to connect my react component to the django server after installing corsheaders and adding it to installed apps in settings.py. I am still getting the following error:

in goolge chrome:
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/teacher/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

In Firefox:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/teacher/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

I have already installed corsheaders and added it to my settings.py together with its middleware, and put allowed all cors origins in same file.

I have also installed axios in react and put the import in my react component

Below is my settings.py code:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]



TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Ateni_LMS_API.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

REST_FRAMEWORK={
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':[
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        
    ],
}
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True
```

Below is the relevant part of my react code:

```
import React from "react";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const baseUrl='https://127.0.0.1:8000/api';
function PopularTeachers(){
    const [teacher,setTeacher] = useState(null);
    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get(baseUrl+'/teacher/').then((response)=>{
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    },[]);
```

Comment: Check your python CORS setting. This can only be solved on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `https` on `localhost`

```
const baseUrl = http://127.0.0.1:8000/api
```

Answer (score -1):

Given that you're running both servers locally there are 2 things you must make sure

1. instead of `python manage.py runserver` do `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`
2. In your app.js replace `https://127.0.0.1:8000/api` with `http://<your_ip>:8000/api`
   You can get the ip address using ifconfig

Other than this make sure whatever your ip address is, you add it to 'allowed hosts' in your settings.py file